# Why isn't my Arraylist class working? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a task to create a tracking System of incoming phone calls with an option menu. Each phone call should belong to an `ArrayList` that displays the user's name and phone number.  My first struggle was storing both a name (string)  and number (double) in an `ArrayList` together. After playing around, this is what I came up with- BUT my third class `remove` and `add` method doesn't work? What is it I am doing wrong? I have looked online and at  examples and I don't understand why `remove` and `add` methods do not work.

**My third class: Where my problem is**

```
public class Incoming {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Person> arr = new ArrayList<Person>();

    Person p1 = new Person("Alex", "01010101");
    Person p2 = new Person("Emily", "0123812"); // I will have 10 people

    void AddCall() {
        System.out.println("Who would you like to  add to the call? Enter p+number");
        String add = input.nextLine();
        Person.add(input);
    }

    void RemoveCall() {
        System.out.println("Which call would you like to answer? Enter p+ caller position"); //NOTE following  will be removed from  queue
        String remove = input.nextLine();
        Person.remove(input);
    }

    void ViewCallerList() {
        System.out.println("The queue has the following  callers: " + Person);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are confusing the add and remove methods of an array list with that of your Person class, that's why it appears to "not work". You need to do `arr.remove()`, except you can't use your string input when using the built in `.add()` and `.remove` list methods.

Comment: you should create a new `Person` object in your `AddCall()` and `RemoveCall()` methods and then add/remove it to/from the `ArrayList` for the whole thing to work properly

Comment: @Droidman hi there, thank you for your response. Hm, the person Arraylist should also be in my main class, I believe. This way I can call it?

Comment: @KiroYakuza Oh I see! Thank you, I will try that now :)

Comment: @Tom the code was edited. But anyway, `Person.add(input);` and  `Person.remove(input);` *actually are* static method calls

Comment: The voting on this question is just incredible. OPs description was just "it doesn't work" and the code doesn't even make sense and still two users thought it is worth an upvote? Unbelievable.

Comment: @Tom I think Droidman was referring to the static methods in the List class which don't exist.

Comment: @KiroYakuza You're wrong, he referes to the `Person` class.

Comment: @Tom my code isn't finished, that's probably why.

Comment: oh well, I might have overlooked the fact the OP passed the `Scanner` itself instead of the result of the `nextLine()` method. I'll delete the original comment, though this doesn't change the matter that non-existent static methods are being referenced as mentioned in the answer

Comment: @Droidman I know, at least one part was correct :).

Answer (score 2):

Your `Person` class does not have any methods named `add` or `remove`, so you can't ever call `Person.add` or `Person.remove`. Instead, you should add and remove items to/from the list itself.

Since you're reading the caller data from the command prompt, you have to figure out which person is being referred to by the text that your user types in. Assuming they type in something like `"John,555-5555"`, you can construct a new `Person` object for John based on that. Using [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), split the text based on the position of the comma, and then create a new `Person` instance to add to your list of callers:

```
public class Incoming {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Person> callers = new ArrayList<Person>();

    Person p1 = new Person("Alex", "01010101");
    Person p2 = new Person("Emily", "0123812"); // I will have 10 people

    private static Person readPerson(Scanner sc) {
        String callerText = sc.nextLine();
        String[] callerData = callerText.split(",");

        return new Person(callerData[0], callerData[1]);
    }

    void addCall() {
        System.out.println("Who would you like to  add to the call? Enter p+number");

        callers.add(readPerson(input));
    }

    void removeCall() {
        // Complete this based on the add method above
    }

    // This should output the list (callers), not a single person
    void viewCallerList() {
        System.out.println("The queue has the following  callers: " + callers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, looks like I got myself really confused. Thank you so much @nbrooks, this really cleared it up for me!